# Regex To Validate A String, But The String Can't Contain n Number Of A Specific Character

Tags: regex

Recently I ran into a validation situation I've been trying to solve with regex. The rules are as such:

- Must start with a capital letter
- Center of the string may be of any length
- Center of the string may have any combination of upper and lower case letters and numbers
- Center of the string may have up to one underscore
- Must end with a number

I have attempted to match this string with the following regex:

```
^(?!_{2,})([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[0-9])$
```

and

```
^(?<=_{0,1})([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[0-9])$
```

Both of these attempts still match cases where there is more than one underscore present. I.E. `App_l_e9` or `App__le9`.

How can you check to see if your regex match, I.E. the `([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[0-9])` part contains zero or one underscore in any place within the middle of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would probably be this

`^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]$`

Explanation:

- `^[A-Z]` Must start with an uppercase letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` A combination of uppercase and lowercase letters and numbers of any length (also 0-length)
- `_?` Either zero or one underscore character
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` Again A combination of uppercase and lowercase letters and numbers of any length (also 0-length)
- `[0-9]$` Must end with a number

This will accept  `A_9` or `AA0_xY8` but for instance not `aXY_34` or `Aasf1__asdf5`

If the underscore in the middle part must not be the first or last character of this middlepart, you can replace the `*` with a `+` like this.

`^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9]$`

So this, won't accecept for instance `A_9` anymore, but the word must at least be `Ax_d9`

Comment: I suppose that would do the trick! Would this be possible with lookaheads or lookbehinds as well? If so, would you mind providing an example?

Comment: @cremedekhan. Something like `^(?!.*_.*_)[A-Z]\w*[0-9]$` would do that. But I'd opt for the answer given here by derpirscher.

Comment: The regex here is prone to backtracking. A better articulatien would be "optionally followed by underscore, followed by any non-underscore aphanumeric character" before the final number group, i.e. ...`(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?[0-9]+$`

Answer (score 1):

You might also start the match with an uppercase A-Z and immediately check that the string ends with a number 0-9 using a positive lookahead to prevent catastrophic backtracking.

```
^[A-Z](?=.*[0-9]$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase char A-Z
- `(?=.*[0-9]$)` Positive lookahead to assert a digit 0-9 at the end of the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` Optionally match any of the listed
- `_?` Match an optional `_`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` Optionally match any of the listed
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aBgjPl/1)

Or with an optional group

```
^[A-Z](?=.*[0-9]$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IrbKjy/1)